# 'SqlAzureExecutionStrategy' does not support user initiated transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

Sporadically my app throws an unhandled exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=The configured execution strategy 'SqlAzureExecutionStrategy'
>   does not support user initiated transactions. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=309381 for additional
>   information.

I'm using Entity Framework where i select table with include to get second table linked by foreign key.

According to link from exception I'm using 'User Initiated Transactions'.
Is Entity Framework Include statement consider as 'User Initiated Transactions'?

I'm using default strategy:

```
SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
```

this code throws exception:

```
requestType = _requestTypes.GetList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == requestTypeId);
```

and this is definition of getlist:

```
    public IEnumerable<RequestType> GetList()
    {
        var retList = DbContext
            .RequestTypes
            .Where(x => !x.Deleted)
            .Include(t => t.RequestTypeWorkStreams)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();

        return retList;
    }
```

Comment: I've got the same issue.

Comment: I'm using Unity as IoC Container for the DbContext with PerRequestLifetimeManager under Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.
Are you having the same config with mine? If it's the case, I want to supplement my sample code with the same error thrown sporadically.

Comment: @JoeLau , I'm facing the same problem now.. Could you please post your solution? thanks.

Comment: @ebramkhalil I think my workaround is not what you need, but I can still share my case.

After some tracing, I found the problem is that the IoC I used is not giving me the same DbContext instance for whole HTTP request. I was trying to make changes to DB with several appService instances/methods, while the DbContext deduced by IoC in each appService instances are found different. Consider the deadline, I simply removed IoC for DbContext, and explicitly indicate the DbContext used on AppService constructors to ensure they are all referring to the same DbContext.